# Android: App stop when trying to get paired bluetooth device

Tags: android

When trying to get the list of the paired device, unexpected error occur that make my app stops. It is new for me to solve all these complex issues.
Here is my MainActivity.java:

```
       package com.example.admin.bluetooth_demo;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.UUID;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ListView lv;
    private ArrayList<String> mDeviceList = new ArrayList<String>();
    private BluetoothAdapter BA;
    Button openbtn,closebtn,searchbtn,senbtn;
    ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>mmPairedDevicesList;
    BluetoothDevice mmDevice;
    BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    EditText entry;
    String msg;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_devices);
        openbtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_open);
        closebtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_close);
        searchbtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_search);
        senbtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
        entry = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_entry);
        msg = entry.getText().toString();
        BA = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        openbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(BA == null){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"No connection!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else{
                    if(!BA.isEnabled()){
                        Intent turnOn = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                        startActivityForResult(turnOn, 0);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Turned on",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Already on", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        closebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                BA.disable();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Turned off" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        searchbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                BA.startDiscovery();
                IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
                registerReceiver(mReceiver,filter);
            }
        });
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                ConnectThread mConnectThread = new ConnectThread(mmPairedDevicesList.get(position));
                mConnectThread.start();
            }
        });
    }
    private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                BluetoothDevice device = intent
                        .getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                mDeviceList.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
                mmPairedDevicesList.add(device);
                Log.i("BT", device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
                ArrayAdapter adp = new ArrayAdapter(context,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,mDeviceList);
                lv.setAdapter(adp);
                adp.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    };
    public class ConnectThread extends  Thread{
        UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
        public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device){
            BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
            mmDevice = device;
            try{
                tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mmSocket = tmp;
        }
        public void run(){
            BA.cancelDiscovery();
            try{
                mmSocket.connect();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                try{
                    mmSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                return;
            }
            final ConnectedThread mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(mmSocket);
            mConnectedThread.start();
            senbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    msg += "\n";
                    mConnectedThread.write(msg.getBytes());
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Data sent!!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }
        public void cancel(){
            try{
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is ConnectedThread.java:

```
package com.example.admin.bluetooth_demo;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    private BluetoothSocket mmBluetoothsocket;
    private InputStream mInputStream;
    private OutputStream mOutputStream;
    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket){
        mmBluetoothsocket = socket;
        InputStream tmpIN = null;
        OutputStream tmpOUT = null;
        try{
            tmpIN = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOUT = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mInputStream = tmpIN;
        mOutputStream = tmpOUT;
    }
    public void run(){
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int begin = 0;
        int bytes = 0;
        Handler mHandler = new Handler(){
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg){
                byte [] writeBuff = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                int begin = (int) msg.arg1;
                int end = (int) msg.arg2;
                switch(msg.what){
                    case 1:
                        String writeMessage = new String (writeBuff);
                        writeMessage = writeMessage.substring(begin,end);
                        break;
                }
            }
        };
        while(true){
            try{
                bytes += mInputStream.read(buffer, bytes, buffer.length-bytes);
                for (int i = begin; i < bytes; i++){
                    if(buffer[i] == "#".getBytes()[0]){
                        mHandler.obtainMessage(1,begin,i,buffer).sendToTarget();
                        begin = i + 1;
                        if(i == bytes-1){
                            bytes = 0;
                            begin = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    public void write(byte[] bytes){
        try{
            mOutputStream.write(bytes);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void cancel(){
        try{
            mmBluetoothsocket.close();
            mOutputStream.close();
            mInputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is Main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.admin.bluetooth_demo.MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Type here:"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button_open"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/editText_entry"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/list_devices"
        android:layout_above="@+id/editText_entry"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:text="Open"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button_open"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:text="Close"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button_close"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button_open"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button_open" />

    <Button
        android:text="Send"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button_close"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button_close" />

    <Button
        android:text="Search"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button_search"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what's the error you're getting? post full stacktrace please

Comment: Here is the error:    Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.bluetooth.device.action.FOUND flg=0x10 (has extras) } in com.example.admin.bluetooth_demo.MainActivity$5@efba352'

Comment: There is literally an answer with exact issue you're having: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27709194/error-receiving-broadcast-intent-act-android-bluetooth-device-action-found-flg Next time, please try googling the exact error you're getting first.